# How do I modify the text field so the cursor is not covered?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to customize my `UITextField`. I have rounded the corners and set the textField border to none in the storyboard. I coded it so that when the textField is tapped, the textField background turns white and the borders turn gray. However, when I run the app, the textField border covers the cursor.

[image]

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // Change the background color for the textField and change the border width for the textField.
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 2
    textField.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9373082519, green: 0.9373301864, blue: 0.9373183846, alpha: 1)

    // Disable the doneButton while editing.
    doneButton.isEnabled = false
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // Change the background color for the textField and change the border width for the textField.
    textField.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9373082519, green: 0.9373301864, blue: 0.9373183846, alpha: 1)
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 0

    // Enable the doneButton when finished editing.
    doneButton.isEnabled = true

    // Set the title of the navigation bar to the text from the titleTextField.
    if titleTextField.text != "" {
        navigationItem.title = titleTextField.text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use a custom class for my UITextFields when I want padding.

```
class PaddedTextField: UITextField {

  override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0))
  }

  override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0))
  }

  override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0))
  }

}
```

Comment: Can I do something similar with a `UITextView`?

Comment: @MikeD., I don't think I've ever needed to subclass UITextView before, but you certainly could. It's just a UIScrollView, which is a UIView. However you can set it directly with `textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 0)`. Of course, use whatever values look good to you.